# Video player displays content of previous file before showing requested video

Tags: ios, html, video, ios7, html5-video

I have a video player and set of buttons each of button triggers different video file to be played. What happens in the iPhone (4S or 5C) safari is the video player displays the content of last played video before displaying new video content. Is it something known? has anyone witnessed similar issue and possibly found workaround?:)

Answer (score 0):

U can try [player stop]; [player SetContentUrl:url]; [player play];

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know results